# finite difference for Black Scholes equation not accurate

Tags: python, numerical-methods, financial, pde

I transformed Blacks Scholes equation to a Heat equation. I try to use explicit finite difference method to solve this PDE and get the price of a call option. I also solve for this by using black schols equation "analytically".

The problem is that I cannot get more accurate in the numerical result. Here is my Python code.

Here is the note of my algorithm:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5h3oewtgjFgdVFpNFJRNTB5LXM/view?usp=sharing

```
import math
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import norm

s0 = 15
sigma = 0.2
r = 0.01
t = 1
Xmax = 10

'''B-S price''' 

def C(s,k,t):
    d1 = (math.log(s/k)+(r+sigma*sigma/2)*t)/(sigma*math.sqrt(t))
    d2 = (math.log(s/k)+(r-sigma*sigma/2)*t)/(sigma*math.sqrt(t))
    return s*norm.cdf(d1)-math.exp(-r*t)*k*norm.cdf(d2)  

print('B-S',  C(s0,10,t))

'''Explicit_finite_difference'''

EFD_n_x = 500
EFD_n_t = 100
EFD_k = Xmax/EFD_n_x
EFD_h = t/EFD_n_t
EFD_xx = np.linspace(Xmax,-Xmax, 2 * EFD_n_x + 1)
EFD_xx = EFD_xx[1:2 * EFD_n_x]

def EFD_T0_Bound(x):
    return max(math.exp(x)-10*math.exp(-r*t),0) 
def EFD_U_Bound(tao):
    return math.exp(Xmax)-10*math.exp(-r*(t-tao))
def EFD_L_Bound(tao):
    return 0
EFD_T0bound = np.vectorize(EFD_T0_Bound)
EFD_lambda = EFD_h*sigma*sigma/2/EFD_k/EFD_k

EFD_A = (np.eye(2 * EFD_n_x - 1) * (1-2*EFD_lambda)
        + np.eye(2 * EFD_n_x - 1, k=1)*EFD_lambda
        + np.eye(2 * EFD_n_x - 1, k=-1)*EFD_lambda)

EFD_Y = np.zeros(2 * EFD_n_x - 1)
EFD_U = EFD_T0bound(EFD_xx)

for i in range(EFD_n_t):
    EFD_Y[0] = EFD_lambda*EFD_U_Bound(EFD_h*i)
    EFD_Y[2 * EFD_n_x - 2] = EFD_lambda*EFD_L_Bound(EFD_h*i)
    EFD_U = np.dot(EFD_A,EFD_U) + EFD_Y       #U_t_i+1 = A * U_t_i + Y

print('Explicit_finite_difference',EFD_U[EFD_n_x - 1 - round(math.log(s0)/EFD_k)])
```

Comment: Do you understand why your accuracy is being limited presently?

Comment: I don't know. I tried to adjust the number of points in my mesh grid, but it does not improve accuracy.

Comment: I'm not clear why either, without stepping through the code and watching the variables change line by line, which is probably the easiest way for you to get the understanding you need

Comment: I believe my code is correct. I guess it might related to error analysis of numerical  PDEs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in my opinion, since you are using an explicit scheme (that is not unconditionnaly stable), you cant set your nb of asset step and your nb of time step indepently. usually people link them together with volatility in order to keep the scheme stable